# How to handle angularJS UI router with dot (.) character

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

I have URL for state function as follows

> `www.test.com/search.go?param=test`

The issue is handle dot(.) character in URL pattern. The URL with dot character not handling properly by angularjs UI router. Let me know how handle this dot character.

Comment: I have one more update , I am using $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

Answer (score 1):

I solved a similar problem when I needed to support existing urls that contained un-encoded base64 strings. The characters in the base64 strings (like ".") were playing havoc with ui-router.

I solved this with ui-router's `$urlMatcherFactoryProvider` ([documentation](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.util.$urlMatcherFactory))

ui-router allows you to specify custom "types" for parts of the url like so.

```
$stateProvider
   .state('oneclickauthlink', {
      url: '/customer/tempauth/{customerID}?authId={authenticationId:base64String}',
      controller: 'TempLinkController'
});
```

You can then, with the `$urlMatcherFactory` provide custom behaviour for these "types". In my case, I needed to URL encode the base 64 strings. You likely need similar behaviour to handle your "."

```
$urlMatcherFactoryProvider.type('base64String', {
    encode: function(val) {
        val = encodeURIComponent(val);
        // console.log("encoded val is " + val);
        return val;
    },
    decode: function(val) {
        val = encodeURIComponent(val);
        return val;
    },
    is: function() { return true; }
});
```

Here's [the documentation](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.util.type:Type) for ui-router's `Type`.

There is no out-of-the-box solution and you may need to test different combinations of the `encode` and `decode` methods. Their function was not immediately clear for me and it took some experimentation to make it work.

Comment: Thanks for you update. $urlMatcherFactory works out :)

Answer (score 0):

On angular UI-Router you define states that can be child of another state (dot notation) but this does not reflect on the URL.

You might have a state called `search` which URL is `/search` and a state called `search.go` with the URL as `/go` which will be translated into `/search/go`

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-and-Nested-Views

Comment: Thanks. Let me clarify the URL pattern http://www.test.com/test/search.do?term=dfdf . Let me know the handling pattern of search.do in this scenario

Comment: This is my state      .state('testsearch', {
        url: '/test/search.go?:param=',
        views: {
          main: {
            templateUrl: 'testTemplate.html',
            controller: 'testcontroller'
          }
        }
      })

Comment: This change will not meet actual requirement. :) @Rafael .

Comment: Actually it should work but i can use only above pattern cannot be alter the current pattern Thanks.